# Joda DateTime Json date format issue

Tags: datetime, gson, jodatime, json

I would like the JSON output to be in a particular date format. My JSON output is:

```
"data":[[{"id":1,"createTimestamp":{"iMillis":1431463708237,"iChronology":{"iBase":{"iMinDaysInFirstWeek":4}}},"startTimestamp":{"iMillis":1420092000000,"iChronology":{"iBase":{"iMinDaysInFirstWeek":4}}},"endTimestamp":{"iMillis":1451541600000,"iChronology":{"iBase":{"iMinDaysInFirstWeek":4}}}}]]
```

But I would like the timestamps to be in this format:

```
2015-05-12T20:48:28.237Z
```

My code:

```
JSONArray a = new JSONArray();
a.add(aList);

JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
j.put("data", a);

JsonArray array = new JSONArray();
array.add(j);

String jason = gson.toJson(array);
```

I tried something like this, but not working

```
for (Noti n : aList) {
                DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
                dtf.parseDateTime(n.getCreateTimestamp().toString());
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JS/Jquery, I used

```
var endTimestamp = new Date(data[i].endTimestamp.iMillis);
```

Comment: I did pose a question to the author and still waiting for a response. But this did solve my issue. I'm still waiting for an answer to convert the JSON output. If I'm not able to, will mark this as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here's your time:

```
1431463708237
```

Note: No quotes. It's a number.

Here's your date format:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Can you see how your time and your date format don't match at all?

Now look what the time is called: It's called "iMillis". Make a guess what this number could be measuring. Now take your favourite calculator and find out how many years it is. Now it's 2015, so make a guess when this time started counting. Then think about the significance of  the year 1970, relating to time stamps. You might for example type "time stamp 1970" into Google.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you correctly at all.....but are you saying the JSON is correct...If I make changes to the UI (js/Jquery) to convert the millis to whatever format I want, I should be good?

Comment: Thank you for pointing in the right direction. Finally was able to fix the issue :)